# Is there a way to read or set Field Level Security on ScorecardMetric object fields in Apex?

Tags: field-level-security

Is there a way to read or set Field Level Security on `ScorecardMetric` object fields in Apex?

I can create a custom field on `ScorecardMetric` but can't use Apex to set FLS for this field.

Answer (score 1):

Currently it is not possible to read or set Field Level Security on `ScorecardMetric` object fields.
Also it is not possible to get `DescribeFieldResult` for such fields or `DescribeSObjectResult` for Scorecard related objects including `Scorecard`, `ScorecardAssociation` and `ScorecardMetric`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way where you can check the field access.

```
String objName = 'Account';                 //Standard Object

//Custom field Value is case sensitive (to lowercase)   
String fieldname = 'customerpriority__c';   

Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> objectFields = new Map<String, Schema.SObjectField>();
//Map to get all fields
objectFields = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();  

if(objectFields.keySet().contains(fieldName) && objectFields.get(fieldName).getDescribe().isAccessible()){                                          
    system.debug('Field is Accessible: '+fieldName);
} else {
    system.debug('Field is not Accessible: '+fieldName);
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: This does not work for ScorecardMetric.